# How to add a value to a line on normal distribution plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, normal-distribution

I would like to add to my plot of normal distribution value:

```
qnorm(.8, 100, 15)
```

to a line:

```
abline(v=qnorm(.8, 100, 15), lty=4 )
```

on x-axis .

My whole code looks like this:

```
sr <- 100; odch <- 15
x <- seq(-4, 4,length=1000) * odch + sr
p <- dnorm(x, sr, odch)
plot(x,p, type="l", lwd=2)
pnorm(80, 100, 15) 
abline(v=80, lty=2)
plot(x,p, type="l", lwd=2)
qnorm(.8, 100, 15)
abline(v=qnorm(.8, 100, 15), lty=4)
text(x=95, y=.01, labels="80%", cex=1.5)
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible: trying it right away raises an error. And it is not clear what is your problem... Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and rephrase your question :)

Comment: please tell us in the question what x and p are like. or give us some similar data.

Comment: I've just added the rest of code that I missed, sorry for that :(.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the problem is. I had a guess at what you are trying to do and it seems to work ok:

```
x <- 0:200
p <- dnorm(x, 100, 15)
plot(x,p, type="l", lwd=2, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", bty="l")
abline(v=qnorm(.80, 100, 15), lty=4)
text(x=95, y=.01, labels="80%", cex=1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got this:

```
v=qnorm(.8, 100, 15)
axis(1,at=v,v)
```

Comment: another way is to use `text`. e.g., `text(v, -0.001, round(v,3), xpd=NA)`